# negate match pattern with contains a substring using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the CNPJ, but, ignore the match if string contains `INTERESSADO`. I need to do this using only regex, can't use if condition.

I thought that this patterns will works: `(?!interessado: ).* CNPJ\W+(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s?\/\d+-\s?\d+)`

```
RECLAMADO: FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
RECLAMADO: FOO FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO FOO FOO - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO IT'S A TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: TEST
INTERESSADO: TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
```

In this case, my pattern match all lines, but i need only the `RECLAMADO` and `INTERSSADO CNPJ's.

I'm using regex101 to test the patterns.

obs: i'm using regex .i and .s flags.

Comment: `(?i)^(?!.*interessado: ).* CNPJ\W+(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s?\/\d+-\s?\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

> get the `CNPJ`, but, ignore the match if string contains `INTERESSADO`

That is, **accepting the lines with `CNPJ`, and rejecting the lines with `INTERESSADO`**.

There might be several ways to accomplish it. One of them is employ the notion of *lookahead* and *lookbehind*. ([More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word))

In short, what we need to do is rejecting `INTERESSADO` with `(?!...)` while processing each line. Here is a simple demo for your case, shown below.

Codes:

```py
import re

str = """RECLAMADO: FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
RECLAMADO: FOO FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO FOO FOO - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO IT'S A TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99
TERCEIRO INTERESSADO: TEST
INTERESSADO: TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99"""

lines = str.split("\n")
regex = "^((?<!interessado).(?!interessado))*(cnpj)[^0-9./-]*(?P<cnpjvalue>[0-9./-]*)$"
ptn = re.compile(regex,re.I|re.S)   # re.I for .i flag  ;  re.S for .s flag
for l in lines:
    m = ptn.match(l)
    if m:
        print("(Matched) cnpjvalue is " + m.group("cnpjvalue"))
    else:
        print("(Ignored)   ... ")
```

Output:

```sh
(Matched) cnpjvalue is 99.999.999/9999-99
(Matched) cnpjvalue is 99.999.999/9999-99
(Ignored)   ... 
(Ignored)   ... 
(Ignored)   ... 
(Ignored)   ... 
(Ignored)   ...
```

Comment: Instead of `^((?<!interessado).(?!interessado))*` that is redundant, you can use `^(?:(?!interessado).)*` or (why not but IMO less efficient), `^(?:.(?<!interessado))*`. It's useless to test backward and forward for each position.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you for clarifying that. In fact, I've already known that it's redundant before I posted it. Because I have emphased that this is a rather **simple demo**, since it just works fine, I would leave the further implementation to the asker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "RECLAMADO: FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99\nRECLAMADO: FOO FOO LTDA - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99\nTERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO\nTERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO FOO FOO - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99\nTERCEIRO INTERESSADO: FOO FOO IT'S A TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99\nTERCEIRO INTERESSADO: TEST\nINTERESSADO: TEST - CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99"
print( re.findall(r'^(?!.*interessado: ).* CNPJ\W+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s?\/\d+-\s?\d+)', text, re.M | re.I) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/arPHRy).
Output:

```
['99.999.999/9999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNOzol/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`)
- `(?!.*interessado: )` - only go on matching if there is no `interessado:` + space on the line
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- - a space
- `CNPJ` - a fixed string
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars (may match across lines! If you do not need it, use `[^\w\r\n]+`)
- `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s?\/\d+-\s?\d+)` - Group 1: your return value, one or more digits and `.`  twice, then one or more digits, an optional whitespace, `/`, 1 or more digits, `-`, an optional whitespace, one or more digits.

Note that `\s` matches line breaks, so use `[^\S\n]` / `[^\S\r\n]` to match horizontal whitespace only.